# JavaScript RegExp: Match comments but not URLs

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to solve this RegExp for a while now but I do not find a solution.

The issue is the following:
I wrote a CSS preprocessor which adds the ability to use normal // styled comments. The script iterates over every single line of the stylesheet.

This is the RegExp is use to remove the comments anywhere in the line:

```
line.replace(/\s{0,}\/\/\s{0,}.*?$/, '')
```

In case of something like this it works perfectly:

```
// body tag
body {
   background-color:red;  // it has a red background
}
```

And results in

```
body {
   background-color:red;
}
```

But it fails when there is an URL present:

```
body {
   background-image:url("http://somewhere.com");
}
```

and results in:

```
body {
   background-image:url("http:
}
```

Please help me by adding the little detail to the RegExp I have not be able to find so that the URL remains whole.

Thank you very much!

Happy Striker

Comment: Try doing `\s{0,}[^:]\/\/\s{0,}.*?$`...

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond. Unfortunately I have already tested this and is does not work for that case. EDIT: Sorry it works, but it causes another issue, because then it no longer matches comments like `// "Description"` (including the ").

Comment: Not working how, as in what does it do?

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty way to fix it is to change the regex to

```
/(?:^|\s+)\/\/.*$/
```

I.e. match only at the beginning of the line or after at least one space.

This would mean something like

```
body {//foo bar
```

would not be recognized as a comment, but

```
body { //foo bar
```

would be.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
line.replace(/\/\/ .*/, '')
```

that will replace everything after '// ' so as long as your comment always has a space between the slashes it will work. Since urls dont have a space between the // this should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible in single step.
How about replacing the problematic part with something not likely to be exist in the line temporarily? :)

```
line
.replace(/:\/\//g, '\\')
.replace(/\s*?\/\/.*/, '')
.replace(/\\/g, '://');
```